# connection refused error when running all tests in a test class with micronaut hibernate reactive

Tags: postgresql, micronaut-data, testcontainers-junit5, hibernate-reactive

When running individually test will pass, but when running all tests from the test class, test will fail with the vert.x java net connection refused exception. For reference, test class inherits from the base test class that sets up the shared testcontainer. It can be observed from the logs that the docker and the postgres container is successfully started, and liquibase migration is successfully performed.

Base test class is given below:

```
@TestInstance(value = TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@MicronautTest(transactional = false)
abstract class AbstractIT : TestPropertyProvider {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        protected var postgresqlContainer: GenericContainer<*>? = null
    }

    @Inject
    open var application: EmbeddedApplication<*>? = null

    override fun getProperties(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        return mutableMapOf(
            Pair("liquibase.enabled", "true"),
            Pair("liquibase.datasources.local.enabled", "true"),
            Pair("liquibase.datasources.local.change-log", "classpath:db/migrations/paka-db.changelog-master.xml"),
            Pair("liquibase.datasources.local.contexts", "test-data"),
            Pair("liquibase.datasources.local.drop-first", "true"),

            Pair("datasources.local.jdbc-url", getPostgreSqlUri().replace("postgres", "postgresql")),
            Pair("datasources.local.driver-class-name", "org.postgresql.Driver"),
            Pair("datasources.local.username", "pakauser"),
            Pair("datasources.local.password", "password"),

            Pair("jpa.local.reactive", "true"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "50"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "true"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.show_sql", "true"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.format_sql", "true"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.highlight_sql", "true"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics", "true"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.connection.url", getPostgreSqlUri()),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.connection.username", "pakauser"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.connection.password", "password"),
            Pair("jpa.local.properties.hibernate.connection.pool_size", "50"),
            Pair("jpa.local.entity-scan.packages", "tech.grgat.paka"),
            Pair("jpa.local.entity-scan.enabled", "true"),
        )
    }

    private fun getPostgreSqlUri(): String {
        if (postgresqlContainer == null || !postgresqlContainer!!.isRunning) {
            startPostgreSql()
        }

        return "jdbc:postgres://localhost:" + postgresqlContainer!!.getMappedPort(5432) + "/pakadb"
    }

    private fun startPostgreSql() {
        if (postgresqlContainer == null) {
            postgresqlContainer = GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("postgres:14.4"))
                .withEnv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "password")
                .withEnv("POSTGRES_USER", "pakauser")
                .withEnv("POSTGRES_DB", "pakadb")
                .withExposedPorts(5432)
//                .withReuse(true)
                .waitingFor(HttpWaitStrategy().forPort(5432))
                .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*database system is ready to accept connections.*\\s", 2))
                .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        }

        if (!postgresqlContainer!!.isRunning) {
            postgresqlContainer!!.start()
        }
    }

    @AfterEach
    open fun stop() {
        postgresqlContainer!!.close()
    }
```

exception generated:

```
12:24:23.385 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-7] INFO  t.g.p.a.c.AccountControllerImpl - creating account::Received the following JSON object: SignUpDto(username=admin2, email=admin2@admin.com, password=pass)
12:24:23.419 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-7] INFO  o.h.r.v.impl.DefaultVertxInstance - HR000002: Vert.x not detected, creating a new instance
12:24:23.479 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-7] INFO  o.h.r.pool.impl.DefaultSqlClientPool - HR000011: SQL Client URL [jdbc:postgres://localhost:49312/pakadb]
12:24:23.482 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-7] INFO  o.h.r.p.i.DefaultSqlClientPoolConfiguration - HR000025: Connection pool size: 50
12:24:23.534 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] ERROR t.g.p.c.e.GlobalExceptionHandler - unexpected error occurred
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:49312
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
```

When running test individually it can be observed that the test successfully passes:

```
12:36:04.107 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] INFO  o.h.r.pool.impl.DefaultSqlClientPool - HR000011: SQL Client URL [jdbc:postgres://localhost:49314/pakadb]
12:36:04.110 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] INFO  o.h.r.p.i.DefaultSqlClientPoolConfiguration - HR000025: Connection pool size: 50
12:36:04.246 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  t.g.p.a.facade.AccountFacadeImpl - create account::Entering with: request -> SignUpDto(username=admin2, email=admin2@admin.com, password=pass)
.
.
.
hibernate successfully persists the generated entity
```

It should also be noted that

```
transactional=false
```

should be set on MicronautTest annotation to avoid another type of error:

```
io.micronaut.transaction.exceptions.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction
```

but that's probably because hibernate tries to create a non reactive session. Or not?

Comment: It looks like it cannot connect to the database.

Comment: exactly, but why is the question. when running a single test, it will always succeed, when running entire test class, it will fail with the connection error

Comment: You do have the after each defined that is closing the container. Try to remove it.